# AngularJS - Passing parameters from directive back to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a new-be to Javascript and AnuglarJS but I have some Java experience. I'm studying AngularJS [developer's guide on directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and have a question.

In the section "Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements" there is a [example/demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MD1lRpMyINwEvgtXuUN2?p=preview). In the example/demo:

The template of the directive myDialog is as bellow:

```
<div class="alert">
  <a href class="close" ng-click="close({message: 'closing for now'})">&times;</a>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

I cannot understand `close({message: 'closing for now'})` here. From the directive's definition:

```
scope: {
  'close': '&onClose'
}
```

So `close` is a reference to `onClose` in the directive's parent.  `onClose` is not defined in the controller but appears in it's template as an attribute and further refer to `hideDialog(message)`:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  {{message}}
  <my-dialog ng-hide="dialogIsHidden" on-close="hideDialog(message)">
    Check out the contents, {{name}}!
  </my-dialog>
</div>
```

Questions:

1. Since `onClose` is not specifically defined in the controller, how can it take and process any input parameter passed from the directive?
2. `hideDialog` in the controller takes a string parameter, but `close` in the directive passes an object `{message: 'closing for now'}` to `onClose`. how `onClose` does the magic of extracting the value from the `message` key of the input and passing it to the target function `hideDialog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Directives have multiple ways of defining values that can then be bound to the directive's controller. The '&' is how you pass a function from a parent controller to the directive controller. In the instance defined above, the parent controller (Controller) has a method (hideDialog) on it's 'scope' (not cool really) that takes a single argument (message). The '&onClose' is bound to the directive controller's 'close' variable. When 'close' is called, it needs to pass 'message' as if it were a named argument (es6 sorta fashion here). This is because of the way the directive controller's variable extends the parent controller's methods under-the-hood, and how it needs to pass variables to that method.